# How do I fix “no model named ‘Gui’” error?

Tags: python, user-interface, module, swampy

I'm trying to learn from Think Python, and have gotten to the point where I need TurtleWorld. Swampy has been successfully imported, but but after following the steps needed, I still cannot import TurtleWorld, getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gui'' each time.
If I try swampy.TurtleWorld, I get this:

```
>>> from swampy.TurtleWorld import*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\resid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\swampy\TurtleWorld.py", line 10, in <module>
    from Gui import Callable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gui'
```

And if i try simply TurtleWorld:

```
>>> from TurtleWorld import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TurtleWorld'
```

I think I've been looking at it for too long to take a step back and figure it out, any help or advice is appreciated.

edit: I have python3.11.4 and got swampy from its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Gui is a module inside of TurtleWorld.py so it likely cannot be installed via a package manager directly. I created a clean python environment and was able to import the module with these steps.

```
conda create -n <env_name> python==3.11.4
```

This creates a python environment

```
pip install swampy
pip install tk
```

This installs all the dependencies I needed to import the module.

Note: from TurtleWorld import * will only work if you downloaded the source code. If you used a package manager like pip or conda it will have to be accessed via swampy.TurtleWorld.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting swampy, unzipping it and instead of putting the file in the Python lip folder, I put its entire contents into the folder.

I’m going to leave this up in case anyone in the future has a similar problem.